# Google Translation API WithAPIKey option error

Tags: go, google-translation-api

I am building a multilingual SAAS website builder in Golang which is run per client. Each client can have their own website and can translate their website in the desired language.

Since the feature is per client, so I collected an API key from client, which I used to translate their site content.

Here is the code,

**V2**

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"

    "cloud.google.com/go/translate"
    "google.golang.org/api/option"
)

func main() {
    translationStrings := []string{"hello"}
    ctx := context.Background()
    opts := option.WithAPIKey(APIKEY)
    c, err := translate.NewClient(ctx, opts)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    defer c.Close()
    resp, err := c.Translate(ctx, translationStrings, language.French,
        &translate.Options{
            Source: language.English,
            Format: translate.Text,
        })
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(resp)
}
```

**V3**

```
translate "cloud.google.com/go/translate/apiv3"
translatepb "google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/cloud/translate/v3"

c, err := translate.NewTranslationClient(ctx, opts)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
defer c.Close()
req := &translatepb.TranslateTextRequest{
    Contents:           translationStrings,
    TargetLanguageCode: "sr-Latn",
}
resp, err := c.TranslateText(ctx, req)
```

The code with V2 works well but the same code with V3 does not work. It gives error:

```
API keys are not supported for gRPC APIs. Remove the WithAPIKey option from your client-creating call.
```

As stated in the error, it is asking me to remove WithAPIKey options. But if I remove this then how will I use the api key for each client.

I have chosen to work with V3 apis because the will be translated as a whole so it will be a large request. I have read in the docs that V3 api can work in batches.

So my questions are:

1. how can I use per client api key structure with api V3?
2. Is it okay to go with the api V2 for the purpose as stated above?

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Translation API v3 does not currently support API keys. It is recommended that you create a service account for Cloud Translation API v3 requests. For information on creating a service account, see [Creating and managing service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts). Your service account must be added to one of the IAM roles added for Cloud Translation API v3.

Comment: thanks for answering. Did you read the question properly ? The requirement is that the clients have to use their own credentials for translation. Can this be achieved using V3 or I have to use V2 for this purpose ?

Comment: In such a case, you would need to use V2.